# How to map different entity types in DyamoDb query

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm modeling an accountant service where I have profile and entities connected to it(ACTIVITIES, EQUITY, HOLDING and LIST).
I have modeled my app, with a single table design like so:

[image]

I'm using `DynamoDbClient.QueryAsync(queryFilter)` method to get List of Documents and parse them:

```cs
IList<Document> result = await _institutionProfileRepository.QueryAllAsync(id);

Document profile = result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.AsString().StartsWith("INSTITUTION")));
Document equ = result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.AsString().StartsWith("EQUITY")));
IEnumerable<Document> lists = result.Where(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.AsString().StartsWith("LIST")));
IEnumerable<Document> activities = result.Where(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.AsString().StartsWith("ACTIVITIES")));
IEnumerable<Document> holdings = result.Where(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.AsString().StartsWith("HOLDING")));

if (profile == null)
    return null;
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

var profileToReturn = new InstitutionProfileDto()
{
    Id = GetAttribute(profile, "Id"),
    Style = GetAttribute(profile, "Style"),
    InvestorType = GetAttribute(profile, "InvestorType"),
    Name = GetAttribute(profile, "Name"),
    Activities = activities.Any() ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Activity>>(activities.ToJson(), options) : null,
    Lists = lists.Any() ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<List>>(lists.ToJson()) : null,
    EquityPortfolio = equ != null ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EquityPortfolio>(equ.ToJson()) : null,
    Holdings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Holding>>(holdings.ToJson())
};
```

There should be a way to do it in an easier way. Recording to AWS documentation [Query and Scan in DynamoDB Using the AWS SDK for .NET Object Persistence Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.QueryScan.html), I can use inbuild mapper for querying one entity, but for multiple of them, there is no example presented.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  What access pattern are you trying to support?

Comment: "There should be a way to do it in an easier way." ...

Unfortunately, this type of question doesn't work very well on StackOverflow as it results in opinion based answers.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Per DocumenDB, there's otherways  to map Document models to POCO classes.  This article might help you: https://www.referbruv.com/blog/posts/working-with-dynamodb-in-aspnet-core-crud-with-example-and-boilerplate